# Filtrar en un data Table con Select Option en uno o dos campos específicos

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

Hola buenas noche necesito filtrar en un dataTable ver: 1.9.4 Específicamente filtrar en un **select option**  dos columnas, algo asi como este ejemplo a continuación: [Ejemplo](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Dicho ejemplo me funciona aparecen todos los **select option** en todas las columnas pero presenta un problema que no carga nada en los **select option**  asi como se mira en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es lo que requiero? Corregir dicho error y me cargue el **select option**, pero solo en dos columnas en especifico que son las dos ultimas columnas que muestro en la imagen de abajo,siendo estas (Pago y Venta)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {



        oTable = $('#SlRData').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "<?= lang('all') ?>"]],
            "iDisplayLength": <?= $Settings->rows_per_page ?>,
            'bProcessing': true, 'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '<?= admin_url('reports/getSalesReport/?v=1' . $v) ?>',
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({
                    "name": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>",
                    "value": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>"
                });
                $.ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'type': 'POST', 'url': sSource, 'data': aoData, 'success': fnCallback});
            },
            'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                nRow.id = aData[9];
                nRow.className = (aData[5] > 0) ? "invoice_link2" : "invoice_link2 warning";
                return nRow;
            },
            "aoColumns": [{"mRender": fld}, null, null, null, {
                "bSearchable": false,
                "mRender": pqFormat
            }, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": row_status}, null, null],
            "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
                var gtotal = 0, paid = 0, balance = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
                    gtotal += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][5]);
                    paid += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][6]);
                    balance += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][7]);
                }
                var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                nCells[5].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(gtotal));
                nCells[6].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(paid));
                nCells[7].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(balance));
            }
        }).fnSetFilteringDelay().dtFilter([
            {column_number: 0, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('date');?> (yyyy-mm-dd)]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
            {column_number: 1, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('reference_no');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
            {column_number: 2, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('biller');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
            {column_number: 3, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('customer');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
            {column_number: 8, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('payment_status');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []}
        ], "footer");


        function fnCreateSelect( aData )
        {
            var r='<select><option value=""></option>', i, iLen=aData.length;
            for ( i=0 ; i<iLen ; i++ )
            {
                console.log(aData)
                r += '<option value="'+aData[i]+'">'+aData[i]+'</option>';
            }
            return r+'</select>';
        }
        /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
        $("tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
            this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
            $('select', this).change( function () {
                console.log( $(this).val())
                oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
            } );
        } );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Doy solución a la pregunta realizada:

```
     oTable = $('#SlRData').dataTable({
                "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "<?= lang('all') ?>"]],
                "iDisplayLength": <?= $Settings->rows_per_page ?>,
                'bProcessing': true, 'bServerSide': true,
                'sAjaxSource': '<?= admin_url('reports/getSalesReport/?v=1' . $v) ?>',
                'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    aoData.push({
                        "name": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>",
                        "value": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>"
                    });
                    $.ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'type': 'POST', 'url': sSource, 'data': aoData, 'success': fnCallback});
                },
                'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                    nRow.id = aData[9];
                    nRow.className = (aData[5] > 0) ? "invoice_link2" : "invoice_link2 warning";
                    return nRow;
                },
                "aoColumns": [{"mRender": fld}, null, null, null, {
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "mRender": pqFormat
                }, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": currencyFormat}, {"mRender": row_status}, null, null],
                "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
                    var gtotal = 0, paid = 0, balance = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
                        gtotal += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][5]);
                        paid += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][6]);
                        balance += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][7]);
                    }
                    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                    nCells[5].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(gtotal));
                    nCells[6].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(paid));
                    nCells[7].innerHTML = currencyFormat(parseFloat(balance));
                }
            }).fnSetFilteringDelay().dtFilter([
                {column_number: 0, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('date');?> (yyyy-mm-dd)]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
                {column_number: 1, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('reference_no');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
                {column_number: 2, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('biller');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
                {column_number: 3, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('customer');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
                {column_number: 8, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('payment_status');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
//agregamos los filtros para dichas columnas
                {
                    column_number: 9, select_type: 'select2',
                    select_type_options: {
                        placeholder: 'Metodo de pago',
                        width: '100%',
                        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
                        allowClear: true
                    },
                    data: [
                        <?php foreach ($paying_by as $row): ?>
                        {value: '<?= $row->name ?>', label: '<?= $row->name ?>'},
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        ]
                },

                {
                    column_number: 10, select_type: 'select2',
                    select_type_options: {
                        placeholder: 'Tipo de venta',
                        width: '100%',
                        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
                        allowClear: true
                    },
                    data: [
                        <?php foreach ($paying_actions as $row): ?>
                        {value: '<?= $row->name ?>', label: '<?= $row->name ?>'},
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    ]
                }
            ], "footer");
```